# Slow records iteration

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance

I need to iterate over 100000s of records, but the iterations works very slow, compare to when there are just 10000 records, even when I use `foreach` loop (`DataRow row in dt.Rows`). When there are 10000 records everything gets iterated in within seconds, but even if there are 50000 records it performs very slow, like 1 records each second. The more the number of records the slower it gets. Is there a way I could speed up the iteration, I can't use `Parrallel.Foreach` as some calculations depends on linear iterations. Could you advise on a better approach?

The problem is not when fetching the data, the records are fetched in good time, but I iterate through them, he is the slowness. The are not many columns to fetch, only around 10 columns with small text data within 50 characters, just the number of records is huge.

I am using ADO.Net code, not EF

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db"].ConnectionString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("GetDetail", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            // Console.WiteLine(row[1].ToString());
            // Some code operations
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a DataReader instead?

Comment: You are trying to loop through 100000s of rows, through a data adaptor, _one row at a time_? And you expect this to be fast?

Comment: Have you tested your query in SSMS? I'd start by optimizing that.

Comment: Based on your statements... "The more the number of records the slower it gets" and "The promblem is not when fetching the data, the records are fetched in good time, but I iterate through them, he is the slowness." It sounds like you update (or do something) with each row . This looks like a design flaw instead. What are your business rules for going through each row, every time?

Comment: It would be useful to know what the data looks like (what's being read in, how much data is being transferred and held in memory)... can you provide a schema or example SQL that is executed to return your resultset? And what kind of processing are you doing? Are you modifying the data in the dataset, or just reading it? We need more data to help you.

Comment: You'll need to post a repro to understand what's going on. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Could whatever you're doing in C# with a loop be done is SQL instead?  Why return so much data?

Answer (score 0):

Is your query optimization at good level to get 50k records ? Check that first thing

My suggestion is to get rid of the dataset and use datareader as I assume you have some calculation based on each row

Also instead of foreach try to use for loop which won't create the object each time

If possible try to all the calculations in SQL server an get back the result

Answer (score 0):

Using a `DataReader` can speed up your process but it really depends on what type of 'work' you are doing and where you perform the 'work'. The first thing I would do is use a `DataReader`, next I would review your process and how and where you do the work.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("GetDetail", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        conn.Open();
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetString(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would probably get batches of results from SQL and work those batches outside of the connection logic, `using (var conn = new SqlConnection...`. You want to get in and get out when retrieving your data, don't do your work within your connection. Make your connection, get your data, close your connection and THEN work with your data. This will be a problem with lots of records, so I'd recommend working with batches/pages of records.